# How to get screen resolution in pixels in Octave?

Tags: matlab, octave

How do I get current screen (display) resolution in Octave?

Equivalent to Matlab's:

```
get(groot, 'ScreenSize')
```

UPD.
The final octave script should run on windows & mac, Octave 4.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's as simple as:

```
get(0, 'screensize')
```

See [Introduction to Graphics Structures](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Introduction-to-Graphics-Structures.html)

Comment: I know there have been changes in MATLAB regarding taking some of the properties out of '0'. Does the command you posted still work in MATLAB, too? I ask simply because Octave might also follow suit in the future

Comment: `groot` seems to be just an alias for 0. At least, in Matlab 2015a output for `get(0)` is the same as for `get(groot)`

Comment: To my knowledge both `get(0...` and `get(groot....` are fully supported by all recent Matlab versions. For future versions it might be necessary to switch to `groot.screensize`, which is the recommended API since Matlab 2014b.