# Stop overlapping figures in Octave

Tags: octave, figure

Is there an easy way to have multiple [figures](https://octave.org/doc/v4.2.0/Figure-Properties.html) distributed evenly across a monitor without manual adjustment?

I've attempted to use the [autoArrangeFigures](https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/48480-automatically-arrange-figure-windows) Matlab community function with little luck.  First I'm hit with various script errors and once addressed, it failed to stop the overlapping figures in a Linux (pop-os) environment.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the contribution.  Close!? the Octave query still stands, I was attempting to show I didn't just blindly hurl the question on SO.

Comment: To be fair, the question references a MathWorks File Exchange function and my solution was written in MATLAB, I feel like this might be an instance where both tags could stand. That close vote seems a bit strong, but likely reflects the fact you've not included any code and this question comes across as minimal-effort, it could have been improved by including your Octave-ammended version of `autoArrangeFigures` so we might have debugged why "it failed to stop overlapping figures".

Comment: About both tags: given there's no MATLAB code, all that's required is an Octave solution. Adding the MATLAB tag is thus superfluous and would restrict an answerer to test and verify their code in both languages. To the closure: I'm always slightly ambivalent about these kind of "How to" questions, especially in MATLAB (less in Octave, granted). The problem is that there's either a built-in function making for a one-line answer with a doc link, or someone has to code quite a bit more than I'd consider a straightforward, practical answer, especially when no code is present in the question itself

Comment: Thanks for the discussion and feedback.  I'll consider all suggestions when raising future questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is a function I've called `tilefig` which tiles figures overlapping only on the toolbars, i.e. maximising plot visibility. Tested in MATLAB but I've done some quick documentation checks on the few less common functions like [`allchild(0)`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/allchild.html) and [`get(0,'screensize')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34235014/how-to-get-screen-resolution-in-pixels-in-octave) and I think it should be Octave compatible.

I've commented the code, but basically the logic is

- Get handles to all open figure objects
- Start from either a given position or the position of the current figure
- Update the positions of subsequent figures in a loop, incrementing the column or row numbers according to the screen size and maximum row/column limits.

Running `tilefig` with no inputs will tile the whole screen starting with the current figure in the top-left.

To make the tiling neat, it also resizes all figures to be the same width/height.

Example result for `tilefig([],4)` with 7 figures

[image: figures]

```
function tilefig( maxrows, maxcols, p )
    % Tile figures to max rows/cols in a grid, can be [] to just use all
    % screen space. Optional input 'p' for top-left tile position, will use
    % current figure if omitted.
    AllFig = allchild(0);          % Get all figures
    pScr = get(0, 'screensize');   % Get screen size
    if nargin < 1 || isempty( maxrows )
        maxrows = inf;
    end
    if nargin < 2 || isempty( maxcols )
        maxcols = inf;
    end
    if nargin < 3                  
        p = get( gcf, 'Position' );   
    end
    pNew = p;       % Current position
    nr = 1; nc = 1; % Row/col numbers
    for ii = 1:numel(AllFig)
        if sum(pNew([1,3])) > pScr(3) || nc > maxcols
            % Exceeded screen width or max num columns
            nc = 1;
            nr = nr + 1;
            pNew(1) = p(1);
            pNew(2) = pNew(2) - pNew(4);
        end
        if pNew(2) < 0 || nr > maxrows
            % Loop back to the first row if exceeds screen height / max row
            nr = 1;
            pNew(2) = p(2);
        end        
        set( AllFig(ii), 'Position', pNew );
        nc = nc + 1;
        pNew = pNew + [pNew(3), 0, 0, 0];
    end    
    % Reverse the overlap
    for ii = numel(AllFig):-1:1
        figure( AllFig(ii) );
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this code, I've given it a quick test this morning and hit the odd error or two:
'error: in indexed assignment of matrix, last lhs index must be ()'.

I'll look to resolve them shortly and give it an end-to-end test.

Comment: Which line is the error on?

Comment: @Wolfie I've taken the liberty of debugging and edited your answer accordingly: the error was on line 31; octave made the decision not to support dot-based syntax and requires the old matlab 'get/set' behaviour. Nice little function :)

Comment: Ah so close, thanks that edit makes sense